# change SVG text to css word wrapping

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, word-wrap

The following code is used to show the text labels of a javascript tree diagram.

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d._children ? -8 : -48; }) /*the position of the text (left to right)*/
        .attr("y", 3) /*the position of the text (Up and Down)*/

        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

This uses svg, which has no word wrapping ability. How do I change this do a normal paragraph

so that I may use css to word wrap it. How do I make this regular text and not svg text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want to use the SVG foreignObject tag, so you would have something like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d._children ? -8 : -48; }) /*the position of the text (left to right)*/
    .attr("y", 3) /*the position of the text (Up and Down)*/
    .attr("width", your_text_width_variable)
    .attr("height", your_text_height_variable)
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Here is a gist by Mike Bostock which helped me: https://gist.github.com/1424037

Comment: I tried, but now no text is showing up. I am trying to apply this to http://bl.ocks.org/1249394, this example. This is where the code from my question is from. Is it not working because the nodes are svg circles?

Comment: sorry, should have included a width and height for the foreignObject - I've amended the code in my answer to make this clearer

Comment: `foreignObject` seems to be about the only solution for this, but be aware that it's not supported in IE (surprise!)

Comment: Is there anyway to mimic the `text-anchor: middle;` effect with a foreignObject?

Answer (score 15):

This is a sample code to word-wrap texts with D3:

```
var nodes = [
    {title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut"}
]

var w = 960, h = 800;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var vSeparation = 13, textX=200, textY=100, maxLength=20

var textHolder = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x",textX)
    .attr("y",textY)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .each(function (d) {
        var lines = wordwrap(d.title, maxLength)

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            d3.select(this).append("tspan").attr("dy",vSeparation).attr("x",textX).text(lines[i])
        }
    });


function wordwrap(text, max) {
    var regex = new RegExp(".{0,"+max+"}(?:\\s|$)","g");
    var lines = []

    var line
    while ((line = regex.exec(text))!="") {
        lines.push(line);
    } 

    return lines
}
```

Comment: Requires a little more customization but I like it. It works.

Comment: I was able to modify your technique to word wrap my X axis labels. Thanks!   Also for reference, @mbostock has a more complex version [WrapLabels](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).  Eventually, SVG 2.0 will include word wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

`foreignObject` isn't supported by IE and Chrome doesn't support transitions on it. If those limitations are okay then I recommend using `foreignObject` because you get all of the formatting of HTML+CSS.

If you need to support IE or transitions then I suggest using a D3 plugin such as [D3plus](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus). It makes text wrapping very easy.

```
d3plus.textwrap()
  .container('selector')
  .draw();
```

Checkout [the docs](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Text%20Wrapping) to read about all of its features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic function using D3.js to wrap text in an svg:text element into multiple svg:tspan children (one tspan per line):

```
    function wrapText(text, width) {
        text.each(function () {
            var textEl = d3.select(this),
                words = textEl.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                word,
                line = [],
                linenumber = 0,
                lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
                y = textEl.attr('y'),
                dx = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dx') || 0), 
                dy = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dy') || 0),
                tspan = textEl.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');

            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = textEl.append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dx', dx).attr('dy', ++linenumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em').text(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
svg.selectAll('text').call(wrapText, 100);
```