# Multiline svg text axis ticks in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am attempting to render a simple bar graph with a label for each bar as axis ticks on the x-axis.  Longer labels run over each other.  Since svg text elements don't support word-wrapping I have been looking into alternative solutions.

Changing the category text that goes into the labels to include the proper <tspan> elements doesn't work since the text isn't set as the innerHtml but rather just the element's raw text.  I have also considered post-processing the labels to remove the text and replace it with tspans, but I haven't found an elegant way to do that yet.

Unfortunately I can't use foreignObject since I need IE9 support, but many of the same markup replacement problems would apply to that solution, anyway.

Has anyone solved this problem well in the past or have any suggestions?

Comment: Very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677878/change-svg-text-to-css-word-wrapping

Comment: Two key differences:
1. Since d3 is generating the tick labels I can't easily replace their markup (as stated in question).
2. I can't use foreign object because of lack of IE9 support (will add to question).

Comment: Can you post an example of how you are aapending the text?

Comment: Text is appended through the d3.svg.axis() functionality, not by me directly.

Comment: Can you not create a horizontal bar graph which will allow a lot more space for the category text (either on the y-axis or within each bar itself)?

Comment: I don't think you should really have to transpose your graph because of a limitation on multiline text, this seems like a basic piece of functionality missing.

Comment: i'm also interested in this capability, extending the axis function with a function that does the text() or html() or append(), or whatever you want.  if you think of a way to it, other than reimplementing axis(), i'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the wrapping manually as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) by Mike Bostock:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

vis.selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, 100);
```