# SVG - How to break line a long line at correct place?

Tags: svg, text

I am having a problem with SVG. I would like the user to be able to write some text and from a certain length, it break a line automatically.

For now it's HTML, it works. I would like to know if this feature exists for SVG

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show some code (HTML, SVG) as [example]. As far as I know there are [ways in Javascript to allow SVG-text-wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240667/svg-text-wrapping#45241723)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can fake something by drawing text on a path, but still looks ugly and no control over whitespace and linebreaks

```html
<style>
  svg {
    background: lightgreen
  }
</style>
<svg viewbox="0 0 400 150">
  <path id="P" pathLength="100" d="M10 25h380M10 75h380M10 125h380" stroke="green"></path>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#P" startoffset="0" text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="middle"
              fill="red" font-size="50px">Hello, what a wonderful SVG world this is</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no attribute on SVG's `<text>` element that allows for automatic text-wrapping.

#### Wrapping to `tspan`s

However you can wrap text within a text-element using various [`<tspan>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan), from MDN WebDocs:

> The SVG  element defines a subtext within a  element or another  element. It allows for adjustment of the style and/or position of that subtext as needed.

#### Books

The `tspan` approach is also explained in-depth in the book:

- Amelia Bellamy-Royds (2015): *SVG Text Layout*, [Chapter 4. Multiline SVG Text](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/svg-text-layout/9781491933817/ch04.html), O'Reilly, ISBN: 9781491933824

#### Proposals ongoing

A page in the W3C wiki from 2013 suggests: [Proposals for Wrappping Text](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Wrapping_Text).