# D3JS wrap text plugin overwritten after updating the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, updating, word-wrap

I've been using the solution from the accepted answer here to **wrap text on a tree diagram**: [Wrapping Text in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784302/wrapping-text-in-d3)

Nevertheless, when I **update the data**, as in:

```
nodeUpdate
  .selectAll("text.nodeText")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .call(wrap, 100)
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

**the wrapping effect dissapears**.

What am I doing wrong?

## ____Edit to show more of the code____

Every node is added with the usual D3JS procedure (enter, update, exit). The problem is that wrapping the updated text does not work.

So we **enter the nodes** on:

```
var nodeEnter = node
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .call(dragListener)
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
  })
  .on("click", click);
```

We **append elements** to the node, like the text of interest:

```
nodeEnter 
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 5)
  .attr("dy", ".95em")
  .attr("class", "nodeText")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .call(wrap, 150);
```

Wrapping **works fine if we do not Update** these nodes. But upon updates like this below:

```
var nodeUpdate = node
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
  });

nodeUpdate
  .selectAll("text.nodeText")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1)
  .call(wrap, 130);
```

The text does not fit into the wrap anymore. **The wrap function** is from the stackoverflow cited above, check the link.

Comment: Can you add enough code to run a demo of the problem so others can reproduce (and fix) the issue?

Comment: @ialarmedalien I just updated the question... with the basic snippets of code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just come across the same issue elsewhere. It is because the text wrap function cannot act on a transition, it requires a selection. To fix your code, just move the text addition and `wrap` calls to prior to the transition:

```
node
  .selectAll("text.nodeText")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .call(wrap, 130);

var nodeUpdate = node
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
  });

nodeUpdate
  .selectAll("text.nodeText")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1)
```