# D3 chart , wrap the text with <tspan> is not appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I use d3 chart [CodeFlower Source code visualization](http://www.redotheweb.com/CodeFlower/) to make some chart

and I also add each node's text with simulating the node's code
like this

```
this.text
    .enter()
    .append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .classed("directory", d => (d._children || d.children ? 1 : 0))
    .text(d => "There is a long long long words")
    .attr("name", d => 'd.name')
    .attr("dy", d => -16)
    .attr("dx", d => 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .call(this.force.drag);
```

[image: the text with long words]

but now because of the text is too long to display. I just need about 10 characters in a line.

therefor I add some  after the text code

```
this.text
    .enter()
    .append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .classed("directory", d => (d._children || d.children ? 1 : 0))
    .attr("name", d => 'd.name')
    .attr("dy", d => -16)
    .attr("dx", d => 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .call(this.force.drag)
    .append("tspan")
    .text(d => "There is a long long logn words")
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("dy", 14)
    .attr("fill", "#000");
```

but the chart with  does not appear in the cart

[image: with <tspan> but the info is not appear]

when I check the dev-tool of chrome. there is the info in the

[image]

So... What is the reason to make the info not appear in the chart???

I just push a minimal on codepen [D3 chart , wrap the text with  is not appear](https://codepen.io/DanaChen/project/editor/ZveMyn).

Comment: could you add a [mcve] here?

Comment: Yeap, I just push the code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/DanaChen/project/editor/ZveMyn)

Answer (score -1):

I finish this question with

`.append("svg:tspan")`

and wrap the text reference [Wrapping Text in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784302/wrapping-text-in-d3)