# Text gets flushed to initial state after applying wrapping function in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have following function for wrapping text in D3 taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784302/wrapping-text-in-d3) answer:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
            x = text.attr("x"),
            y = text.attr("y"),
            dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
            tspan = text.text(null)
                        .append("tspan")
                        .attr("x", x)
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .attr("dy", dy + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan")
                            .attr("x", x)
                            .attr("y", y)
                            .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
                            .text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I initialize the nodes in a following manner:

```
const nodes = [1, 2, 3]
const nodesTextsEnter = vis.g.selectAll('text.node').data(nodes).enter()
const nodesTextsUpdate = vis.g.selectAll('text.node').data(nodes)
vis.g.selectAll('text.node').data(nodes).exit().remove()
        
nodesTextsEnter.append('text')
                .attr('x', (d, i) => i*30)
                .attr('y', (d, i) => i*30)
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('dominant-baseline', 'middle')
                .attr('font-size', 12)
                .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr('opacity', '0')
                .transition()
                .attr('opacity', '1')
                .attr('x', (d, i) => i*30)
                .attr('y', (d, i) => i*30)
                .text('This is a long text')
                .call(wrap, 30)

nodesTextsUpdate
                .transition(transitionDuration)
                .attr('x', (d, i) => i*30)
                .attr('y', (d, i) => i*30)
                .text('This is a long text')
                .call(wrap, 30)
```

The problem is that while debugging `wrap` function, I see all the wrapping changes happening to the nodes, but then at some point (specifically, I figured it is happening on `timerFlush()` in `wake` function of `timer.js`) content of nodes gets flushed as though it was never wrapped.

Why this could be happening? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works if you set the text contents before the transition:

```
nodesTextsEnter.append('text')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => i*30)
    .attr('y', (d, i) => i*30)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('font-size', 12)
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('opacity', '0')
    .text('This is a long text') // this line was moved up
  .transition()
    .attr('opacity', '1')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => i*30)
    .attr('y', (d, i) => i*30)
    .call(wrap, 30);
```

Otherwise, the value of `d3.select(this).text()` in `wrap` is empty and therefore `words` only contains the empty string.